# 3D version of z-index

Tags: css, colors, 3d, z-index, layer

I've made a cube (well, three cubes) using html and css, and I've used three different cubes to layer different colours (of different opacities), one over the other.

However, what I want to be a bottom layer is opaque black and white, and you can't see the translucent colours over the top.

I realise that a z-index only works with 2d stuff but it'd be helpful if anyone knows a way to layer a 3d object inside another.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After doing like @sol instructed, we can help you more. But look into `transform-style: preserve-3d;`.